# jquery ajax to return partial view with HTML dataType from controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a search form, I want to change items when user click filtering without refresh page.

I use this jquery

```
var newUrl = "store/productlist?" + queryString;
window.history.pushState(null, null, newUrl);

$('#loadingModal').modal('show');
$.ajax({
    url: newUrl,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (result) {
        $("#ProductsPartialView").append(data);
        $('#loadingModal').modal('hide');
    }
});
```

and in store controller .

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Productlist(string category, string factory, string page, string order)
    {//get productlist
     return PartialView("_ProductsPartialView",  product);}
```

but don't go to action.

Comment: any errors on console in browser?

Comment: No, dont have any error.

Answer (score 0):

some minor changes in your code

```
var newUrl = '@Url.Action("productlist","store")';
var category = '';
var factory = '';
var page = '';
var order = '';
$.ajax({
    url: newUrl,
    type: "GET",
    data: {'category': category, 'factory' : factory , 'page' :  page, 'order': order}
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (result) {
        $("#ProductsPartialView").append(data);
        $('#loadingModal').modal('hide');
    }
});
```

let me know if this help you

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.

```
   $.get(newUrl, function (data) {
    $("#ProductsPartialView").empty();
    $("#ProductsPartialView").append(data);
    $('#loadingModal').modal('hide');

}).fail(function (xhr, err) {
    alert("readyState: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status);
    alert("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
});
```